# Is there a way to calculate the intensity of light absorbed that passed through a solid?

Tags: visible-light, laser, intensity

So I have lab I need to do for school and I need a formula that calculates the intensity of light transmitted through a solid (in my case sheets of paper). I had a probe that measured the intensity of an incident laser beam in the lux unit. Apparently Beer's law is only for liquids. I know paper also scatters the light but I can ignore this.

The info I have is:

- The distance between the laser and probe was 1.5cm (the sheets of paper were placed directly in front of the probe and the intensity was measured)
- The wavelength of the laser as well as its output power (1mW 630nm)
- The thickness of the barrier (The thickness of an A4 sheet of paper * 1 through 5)

I appreciate any help and ideally also tell me the name of your formula so I may research it further. Thanks!

Comment: Beer’s law does not apply only to liquids. More importantly, why not do the experiment and plot the data? Something may well suggest itself.

Comment: You can't do this without material properties of your specific paper. If you have measuring equipment then you should just measure it. What is the objective of your lab?

Comment: I did do the experiment and I did plot the data, It's just that I'd ideally also have a formula to go along with it. The data I plotted gave me an exponential decay trend.

Comment: The objective of my lab is to answer my question which is "How does adding barriers between a light source and a surface affect the intensity of the light incident on said surface?" I did this by shining a laser at a probe that detects light intensity in lux. What do you mean by material properties? Isn't that just a general fact for plain white A4 paper?

Comment: I am looking for a regression function to match my trend line, I don't need to calculate the exact number

Comment: Given what you say, just fit to an exponential decay. Any decent curve fitting software can do that.